# Align second y axis with the one on the left?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, yaxis

I introduced a twin yaxis to plot the cumulative but the 0 does not start at the bottom of the image or is at least at the same height of the left yaxis.

How to align the 0 point of the right to the y on the left?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,1.5*2.5))
ax.hist(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))
axt = ax.twinx()
axt.plot(np.arange(100), np.arange(100), ls=':', c='r')
```

[image: img]

Unfortunate with with `set_ylim` it changes the tick-resolution.

[image]

Comment: Try `axt.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the two y-axes to have equal limits with the command

```
axt.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
```

*after* you have performed all plotting commands. Equally, if you only want the lower values (the 0) to coincide, you can do

```
axt.set_ylim([ax.get_ylim()[0],axt.get_ylim()[1]])
```

This works because `ax.get_ylim()` returns a tuple, where the first entry is the lower limit and the second value is the upper limit of the displayed axes range. `set_ylim()` in turn expects a two-element iterable (e.g. a list or a tuple), which you can construct on the fly.

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by [tmdavison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588071/tmdavison) in the comments, one can also just pass one of the limits to `set_xlim()`, thereby leaving the other limit unchanged (see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html) for details). This is done with the keywords `bottom` and `top`. For the example in the OP, the way to only set the lower limit of the twin axes to 0, the according command would be

```
axt.set_ylim(bottom=ax.get_ylim()[0])
```

Comment: Or you could just change the bottom limit and leave the top limit unchanged. `axt.set_ylim(bottom=0)` would do that.

Comment: @tmdavison Good point, I didn't know that you can only fix one limit. Do you mind if I include your comment in my answer?

Comment: Sure, no problem